# Is there any drill through possible within a single table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a table Visual where the Data like Date,Description,Value,Type are present. If the one of the 'Type' value is clicked the Next row should expand showing the details related to that type , like - > ID, Message. Also the Expanded detailed row should come up only when the selected user group does the Type selection within the same Power BI table visual.

I have created 2 tables.I have created the relationship between these two tables using the ID column.Since its the OLAP based Report, I have created the RLS implementation on the 2nd table for the particular user group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a hierarchy in your model. In the fields pane right-click Type and click **New hierarchy**. Then right-click ID and click **Add to hierarchy**. Many visuals like the Matrix and others, will then offer drill down.

[image]